# AWS Lambda: Monitoring lambda timeout that was triggered by SNS.

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda that was triggered by SNS message. Many time, it has reached the max duration allowed by AWS, and AWS killed it immediately.

I have to either dig into the Lambda logs or the lambda duration chart to find out about the error.

Are there a better way to report this kind of errors?

Comment: How about CW alarms based on error metric for that lambda? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-create-alarm.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some 3rd party tools that help you monitor your environment and provide exactly that - filter on specific errors and drill down to what happened there (the input event, the outgoing HTTP requests etc.).
Moreover, you can also configure alerts on specific errors that you will get via slack/mail.

Disclosure: I work for Lumigo, a company that does exactly that.